avoiding barrel files in a typescript monorepo bundled with vite
Popular wisdom and guidance advise avoiding barrel files, but I am struggling to do so without using wild cards in tsconfig paths and package.json exports.
I have a monorepo that has a tsconfig-base.json in the root, and I want my imports to look like
import { Link } from '@my/component-library/atoms/Link
I need to add an entry into the paths array in the tsconfig-base.json for EVERY directory that I want to resolve without a barrel file:
"paths": {
  "@my/component-library/atoms/Link": [
    "./packages/component-library/src/atoms/Link"
  ],
  "@my/component-library/atoms/LinkButton": [
    "./packages/component-library/src/atoms/LinkButton"
  ],

I tried the code below, but it did not work. I got could not find module errors without adding an entry for EVERY directory that I want to import.
"paths": {
  "@my/component-library/atoms/*": [
    "./packages/component-library/src/atoms/*"
  ],

The same goes for package.json exports. I need to add an entry for every directory I want to import in @my/component-library/package.json
"exports": {
  ".": {
    "types": "./dist/esm/index.d.ts",
    "import": "./dist/esm/index.js"
  },
  "./atoms/Link": {
    "import": "./dist/esm/atoms/Link/Link.js",
    "types": "./dist/esm/atoms/Link/Link.d.ts"
  },
  "./atoms/LinkButton": {
    "import": "./dist/esm/atoms/LinkButton/index.js",
    "types": "./dist/esm/atoms/LinkButton/index.d.ts"
  },

I tried the code below, but it did not work:
"exports": {
  ".": {
    "types": "./dist/esm/index.d.ts",
    "import": "./dist/esm/index.js"
  },
  "./atoms/*": {
    "import": "./dist/esm/atoms/**/*.js",
    "types": "./dist/esm/atoms/**/*.d.ts"
  },

This is not sustainable if I have 80+ components or directories.
Is there a better way of doing this?  Can this be done with wildcards?

The setup that worked for me in a Turbo monorepo was to install as a dependency "@your-package":"*" in package.json of your main workspace
Then in your tsconfig.json of your main workspace, add :
{..., // the rest of your tsconfig.json file
"paths": ["../path/to/packages/your-package"]
}

I did not use exports in @your-package package.json file.
This helps typescript to resolve types and use their latest definitions.
Hope that would help!
